# hashCode and equals with a list property

Tags: java, equals

I have a class with a **for-loop within the equals/hashCode**:

```
class User {

private List<Task> tasks;
private ZonedDateTime date;


@Override
public int hashCode() {    
    int hash = 17;
    hash = 31 * hash + (date != null ? date() : 0);
    for (var task : tasks) {
        hash = 31 * hash + task.hashCode();
     }

    return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

        final User other = (User) obj;

        if (tasks.size() != other.tasks.size()) return false;

        // needed?
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
            if (!tasks.get(i).equals(other.tasks.get(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return Objects.equals(timeStamp, other.timeStamp) && Objects.equals(tasks, other. tasks);

    }
}
```

I am used to have this version **(version 2)** of equals/hashCode, which is shorter and faster:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(date, tasks);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

    final User other = (User) obj;
    return Objects.equals(timeStamp, other.timeStamp) && Objects.equals(tasks, other. tasks);

}
```

Can I replace the former equals/hashCode with the version 2 without worrying about correctness?

Are both versions return the same result?

**To sum up:**

for typcial List implementation we can use version 2 instead of version 1.

**One additional question related to this:**

Will **version 2** be also valid, if the property `task` is not a `List` but a `Stream`? (`Stream<Task> tasks`).

Comment: They are not semantically identical. The hash code values will be different; the handling of nulls in the list is different.

Comment: I dont understand that. The list has no null values..

Comment: There is nothing in this code to suggest there can never be nulls in the list.

Comment: Note that the for loop (and size check) in the first method is redundant because you check `Objects.equals(tasks, other. tasks)` afterwards, which will do the same for a correctly-implemented list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the specific `List` implementation.
Let's look at what `Object.equals` does:

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```

So it checks for a couple of trivial cases, then calls `a.equals(b)`, which means that it will call the `equals` method of your list. But if you're using some custom `List` or just some list that doesn't compare the elements one by one, then the two implementation will be different.

For any sane implementation, `equals` should iterate over the elements and compare each one using `equals`. This is what `AbstractList` does.

Also note that your hash code will probably change between implementations.

Comment: So you say, as long as I am using standard java list implementation (e.g. ArrayList, etc), I dont need the for-loop within my equals/hashCode and can use my **version 2** instead?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.

Comment: In fact some IDEs will generate an `equals` and `hashCode` pretty similar to "version 2" given your `User` class.

Comment: So the **deep** equality check is already done by using `Objects.equals(tasks, other. tasks)`, hence no need to manually loop through each element of the tasks-List.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the deep equality depends on the `equals` of the `List` itself. But as long as you're not using anything too weird, it should perform a *deep* comparison. If you're using something from `java.util`, you'll be fine.

Comment: one question: if one property of Task is changed within the element in this tasks-list, will **version 2** also work like **version 1 (with the for-loop)**?

Comment: What do you mean by "work like"? In both cases it will perform a deep comparison and the `equals` method of `Task` will be called. If the tasks are different, you'll get `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Version 2 will work just fine, though it will return slightly different hash codes.

Comment: So I dont need the for-loop? The former maintainer used the for-loop within the equals/hashCode and I am worrying about it with version 2 of equals/hashCode. So you say, they produce the same result, even the hashCode is different. But this should be not the problem as long as the equality checks will be the same..